# ASP.NET Identity using a MySQL Database gives my identity tables a wrong name

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, identity

I have a mysql database hosted in Azure, and I have MVC application om my computer.
I wanted to use the Identity framework to keep track of my users. The identity tables got generated in my database, but they all have wrong names:

[image]

because when i want to add a new user on my register page i get the following error:

**Table xxxxxxxx.aspnetusers doesnt exist.**

I know this is because my table names are wrong.
But i have no clue why the tables got added with the name **my_aspnet_users** in stead of **aspnetusers**.

I followed this article as a guide:
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788357/How-to-set-up-application-using-ASP-NET-Identity-w

I also tried to edit my ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("WebShopDatabaseContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("aspnetusers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("aspnetusers");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("aspnetuserroles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("aspnetuserlogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("aspnetuserclaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("aspnetroles");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try configure with the actual table names, like `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("my_aspnet_users");`? And similar for other tables.

Comment: This wouldn't work because it doesn't rename the tables as it is now. So if i would change that it would stay te same. But il try it to be sure.

Comment: It is not for the purpose of renaming the tables, it is to let the `EntityFramework DbContext` know which tables to use, having alternative names.

Comment: that acctually worked, if you want you can post an answer and i will aprove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to try to figure out why your table names are as-is,
but you can configure your `DbContext` to use the actual ones,
like here below.
Do the same for each table.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("my_aspnet_users");
```